# How to reverse a sort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, sorting

```
public class Sort {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    //fill the array with random numbers
    int[] unsorted = new int[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      unsorted[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }

    System.out.println("Here are the unsorted numbers:");
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      System.out.print(unsorted[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    int[] sorted = new int[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      int hi = -1;
      int hiIndex = -1;
      for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if(unsorted[j] > hi) {
          hi = unsorted[j];
          hiIndex = j;
        }
      }
      sorted[i] = hi;
      unsorted[hiIndex] = -1;
    }
    System.out.println("Here are the sorted numbers: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      System.out.print(sorted[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

So this is in descending order but I want to reverse it.
I tried changing the `if(unsorted[j] > hi) {`
to a `if(unsorted[j] < hi) {` 
[edit:changed greater than to less than, both were same]

Comment: what exactly did you try to change?

Comment: I tried to change the line:  if(unsorted[j] > hi) to  if(unsorted[j] < hi) to try to change it to ascending order but it does not work. I get ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException

Comment: [edit] and correct your question..also read [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use Collections.sort

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you want the numbers to be in ascending order. So for descending, you assume that compared number would be -1 and all other number must be grater than this -1, now instead of -1 use the maximum value a number could be. Assign `Integer.MAX_VALUE` where you were assigning -1. So change your code like this:

```
 int[] sorted = new int[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      int hi = Integer.MAX_VALUE;   
      int hiIndex = i;
      for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if(unsorted[j] < hi) {
          hi = unsorted[j];
          hiIndex = j;
        }
      }
      sorted[i] = hi;
      unsorted[hiIndex] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain why you change the -1 to INTEGER.MAX_VALUE ?

Comment: Just doing the opposite exactly why you use -1. If you understand why you used -1 for descending, then you'll know why max value for ascending.  :)

Comment: @CC31 As you used the smallest value to compare so that no value in you array is smaller than that you set `hi=-1`, so in ascending case you need to initialize `hi` to the maximum possible value so that no number in your array will be greater than that. If your array contains the maximum Integer value then this algorithm might not work.

Comment: If you change `int hiIndex = -1;` to `int hiIndex = i;` it will work for the case where the value is max_value. @CC31 . Thanks.